# Explain why non-zero bivectors on a plane are called pseudo-vectors of the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I answered it by saying pseudo-vectors changes according to the rotation of the vector on the plane like theta rotating clockwise 90 degrees. Am I right?

Comment: I don't understand your answer, so I'll give my own: It's because in $\Bbb R^3$ the dimension of the subspace of bivectors $(3)$ is equal to that of the subspace of vectors.  So there is a vector space isomorphism between the subspaces.  But they behave a little different multiplicatively.  For instance, unit vectors square to $1$ but unit bivectors square to $-1$ (assuming the Euclidean dot product).  So bivectors have some of the properties of vectors, but not all.  Thus *pseudo*vectors.

Comment: what is a subspace of a vector? I'm guessing it is the pseudo vector. I'm new to this type of Math

Comment: Let $V$ be some vector space.  So then $V$ is a set with two operations -- called addition and scalar multiplication -- that satisfies a bunch of axioms.  Consider some sub*set* of $V$.  If that subset *also* satisfies all of those axioms with the same two operations, then that subset is called a sub*space*.  The set of all vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ (where I use that notation a little loosely) is a subspace and so is the set of all *bi*vectors.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, where are you learning about bivectors?  Is this in some linear algebra class or are you just reading a book/ pdf on your own?

Comment: this is an applied modern algebra class @Bye_World. I was caught off guard by doing linear algebra in this class

Comment: OK.  To really understand this part of your course, you're going to want to learn some more regular linear algebra (the stuff most students learn *before* they get to multivectors).  If you have the time, you might consider picking up the book [*Linear and Geometric Algebra*](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Geometric-Algebra-Alan-Macdonald/dp/1453854932) by Alan Macdonald.  It is relatively cheap and short.  But it goes over all the basic linear algebra stuff while also covering multivectors.  It could help you out.

Comment: thanks. I have a lot of Math books so I will add to my collection